# Visualizing the difference curve in a 2D plot?

Tags: plotting

I have two functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$. I wish to perform two tasks on a 2-dimensional figure:

1. Plot the curve where each point satisfies $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$.
2. Mark one side of the curve with red.

I tried to use Plot3D like the following

```
myfunc[x_, y_]:= If[f[x, y] < g(x, y), 1,0];
Plot3D[myfunc[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

It gives what I expected, but how can I do this in a 2D plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RegionPlot[f[x, y] <= g[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't know this before.

Answer (score 4):

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y] - g[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  Contours -> {{0}}, ContourShading -> {None, Red}]
```